# How to include function output as child in Fitted Box - RenderBox was not laid out

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

*Edited to clarify return for when condition is not met in displayoperator() has already been set.

I am trying to make the text size dynamic in the calculator display (where you see the operands and operators as you press the buttons) so the text will decrease in size once it hits the full length of the screen instead of creating a new line.

To do this I am using FittedBox, and the examples I find online provide a hardcoded text value as the child, which is working fine with my code. However when I replace the "text" with my function I end up with a blank screen, and the error RenderBox was not laid out in the console.

The error suggests that it cannot get the size of my (I'm guessing) function, why is this an issue when my function is returning a String variable but is working fine if it's a hardcoded String? How can I fix this?

The relevant snippets of code are below:

In Stateful Widget:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(child:
    Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 50), child:
      Column(children: <Widget>[
       FittedBox(fit: BoxFit.scaleDown, child: Text(displayoperation().toString(),style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60))),
```

where the displayoperator function is (value1 being a num variable):

```
displayanswer() {
    if (operator == null && evaluateanswer == true) {
      return "$value1";
    }
    return "";
```

Error in detail:

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#3fb05 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1930 pos 12: 'hasSize'

Answer (score 0):

Set the return type of displayAnswer function and return some string if this (operator == null && evaluateanswer == true) condition is not satisfied.

Your function should look like this

```
String displayanswer() {
    if (operator == null && evaluateanswer == true) {
      return "$value1";
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rudra, actually there already is a fall back return type for when the condition is met. It's my fault I've missed that out since I have about 3 conditions before returning a value if no conditions are satisfied. Anything else I should be looking at?

Comment: This is probably happening because the return string is empty. Text string should not be null or empty inside FittedBox. I'm not sure why this happens but this is the issue. A quick fix for this issue could be, you should return a space(" ") string instead of empty("") string in your displayanswer() function